# Le « fait français » : quel genre de fait, définition ?

Tags: sens, expressions, usage

> Je ne comprends pas spontanément un mélange d'argot et de verlan, mais
>   j'y reconnais néanmoins le **fait français**.

J'ai utilisé cette expression pour signifier que j'en reconnais la génétique, la facture, de langue française, à défaut d'en comprendre le sens. Puis je me rends compte que je ne saurais définir le *fait français* ni dire si l'emploi que j'ai voulu en faire était adéquat. Le professeur [Benoît Melançon](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beno%C3%AEt_Melan%C3%A7on) discute de deux usages de l'expression :

> Un usage géographique : le *fait français* n’est pas franco-hexagonal.
>   On parle le plus souvent de *fait français en Amérique* ou de *fait
>   français au Canada*, bref, là où la langue et la culture françaises
>   sont minoritaires.
>
> Un usage linguistique : les choses iraient mal. Voilà pourquoi le *fait
>   français*, pourtant *bien vivant*, risque de *reculer* et voilà pourquoi il
>   faut travailler *à son rayonnement* ou *à son maintien*.
>
> [ L’Oreille tendue (blogue), [*De deux choses l’une ?*](http://oreilletendue.com/2012/10/01/de-deux-choses-lune/) (2012), Benoît
>   Melançon ]

Des usages j'extrapole qu'on le définit comme la langue française *là où la langue et la culture françaises sont minoritaires*, ou deuxièmement comme l'*état du français* anthropomorphisé en patient (se porte bien, convalescent etc.)... est-ce exact, exhaustif ?

---

- Quelle est la définition du *fait français* et en connaît-on l'origine ?
- Sur quelle acception/sens du nom *fait* ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fait), [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fait/32729?q=fait#32645))
  l'expression s'appuie-t-elle ?
- L'emploi en *exemple* est-il compatible avec le sens de l'expression,
  avec un autre sens du *fait* ; on y voit un nom ou un verbe (participe passé) et on y comprend quoi ?

Comment: Le terme "franco-hexagonal" me fait bien rire. C'est une variante de "franco-français" ou ça veut dire autre chose ?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Que veut dire "franco-français", ça fait comme _archi_ ? J'imagine que ça donne la France dans sa dimension géographique, et de manière appuyée, métropolitaine, par métonymie ? La géométrie et la géographie ?

Comment: C'est quelque chose de très français (et exclusivement français), en général c'est un peu péjoratif. D'après le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/franco-fran%C3%A7ais), c'est soit quelque chose de "fait en France, par des français, pour des français", soit quelque chose de typiquement français ("franchouillard" donne bien le côté un peu péjoratif).

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Merci, je vois. Je suis davantage habitué à des usages pour parler des francophones au Canada, comme les _Franco-Manitobains_, par exemple. Je sais que la République est indivisible, d'où ma perplexité face à l'expression. Je ne connais pas bien l'auteur (je l'ai cité une fois ou deux je crois) mais il y a assurément une pointe d'humour dans ses textes...

Comment: Oui tout de suite, en opposition à Franco-manitobain, ça prend tout son sens !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La définition qu'il me semble utile de pointer en réponse est celle de "fait" au sens suivant :

> "Situation telle qu'elle existe (sans référence juridique, sans fondement légal) [...] P. ext., cour. État de chose, situation." [1](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/Fait)

En parlant des pays, des langues, ou des ethnicités, on peut ainsi parler du "fait américain", du "fait algérien", etc. pour se référer à la situation réelle de ces pays / langues / personnes, distincte des institutions, principes, règlements et autres idées abstraites qui leur sont associés.

Le "fait français" correspond à cette construction. Je dirais qu'il s'agit d'un usage recherché, académique, compatible avec l'exemple sans risque d'ambiguïté avec une autre acception de "fait", mais dépendant peut-être du contexte.

Voici quelques autres exemples d'usage :

> En mars 1962, dans une note intitulée « Le **fait algérien** au Maroc », Roger Seydoux estime que « si les relations sont en surface étroites et cordiales, en profondeur des failles sont apparues ou se sont élargies.» [2](https://books.google.com/books?id=nqvqCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT166&lpg=PT166&dq=%22le+fait+algerien%22&source=bl&ots=v30XuGHQv1&sig=dEj5maPglVQ2Fea2m_KFVJj1CXc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyxPnZprDRAhUE0mMKHfHgCD0Q6AEIITAD#v=onepage&q=%22le%20fait%20algerien%22&f=false)

Il s'agit de la réalité de la situation entre algériens et marocains.

> L'introduction de l'enseignement du **fait religieux** dans l'école publique française a été précédée d'un long débat public durant vingt ans. [3](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enseignement_du_fait_religieux_en_France)

L'enseignement du fait religieux regarde la religion sous l'angle de l'histoire, de la littérature, des sciences sociales - contrairement à un "enseignement de la religion" qui serait peut-être plus proche d'un catéchisme.

> Parce qu'il s'agit de comprendre le **fait russe** et non de le rêver, Besançon mobilise l'histoire religieuse et politique, la littérature et le monde des idées. [4](http://www.lefigaro.fr/lefigaromagazine/2012/07/05/01006-20120705ARTFIG00472-toute-la-russie.php)

L'auteur se réfère là à la réalité de la Russie, distincte des fantasmes que chacun peut y projeter.

Comment: Merci ! C'est parce qu'aucune préposition ne suit _fait_ qu'on rejette une interprétation comme participe passé, comme ds. _fait sur-mesure_ ou _fait en France_ ? Avez-vous un exemple d'usage avec un autre adjectif que _français_  et provenant d'une publication établie ailleurs qu'en Amérique du nord, je dois admettre ne jamais l'avoir vu hors du contexte socio-politique canadien ou nord-américain ou autrement qu'avec français dans ce sens-là.

Comment: Désolé, je ne saurais pas expliquer pourquoi il n'y a pas à mon avis d'ambiguïté avec d'autres sens de "fait". En tout cas, il ne s'agit pas du tout d'un sens limité à l'adjectif "français" ou à un usage nord-américain. Voici des exemples :

Comment: Exemples ajoutés au corps de la réponse